# Prepending to a dask dataframe in parquet storage

Tags: pandas, dask, dask-distributed

What is the recommended way to prepend data (a pandas dataframe) to an existing dask dataframe in parquet storage?

This test, for example, fails intermittently:

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def test_dask_intermittent_error(tmp_path):
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 1), columns=['A'],
                      index=pd.date_range('20130101', periods=100, freq='T'))
    dfs = np.array_split(df, 2)

    dd1 = dd.from_pandas(dfs[0], npartitions=1)
    dd2 = dd.from_pandas(dfs[1], npartitions=1)

    dd2.to_parquet(tmp_path)

    _ = (dd1
         .append(dd.read_parquet(tmp_path))
         .to_parquet(tmp_path))

    assert_frame_equal(df,
                       dd.read_parquet(tmp_path).compute())
```

gives

```
.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py:3812: in to_parquet
    return to_parquet(self, path, *args, **kwargs)
...
fastparquet.util.ParquetException: Metadata parse failed: /private/var/folders/_1/m2pd_c9d3ggckp1c1p0z3v8r0000gn/T/pytest-of-jfaleiro/pytest-138/test_dask_intermittent_error0/part.0.parquet
```

We considered relying on a simple append and figuring out order after retrieval, but this seems to be hitting a different [bug](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/3098), i.e.:

```py
def test_dask_prepend_as_append(tmp_path):
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 1), columns=['A'],
                      index=pd.date_range('20130101', periods=100, freq='T'))
    dfs = np.array_split(df, 2)

    dd1 = dd.from_pandas(dfs[0], npartitions=1)
    dd2 = dd.from_pandas(dfs[1], npartitions=1)

    dd2.to_parquet(tmp_path)
    dd1.to_parquet(tmp_path, append=True)

    assert_frame_equal(df,
                       dd.read_parquet(tmp_path).compute())
```

gives

```
ValueError: Appended divisions overlapping with previous ones.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you avoid using a "_metadata" file when writing (which you will with the default settings and pyarrow), then you could simply rename your files, to assure that the prepended partition occurs before the rest, when listed by glob. Normally, Dask will begin naming with a serial number 0.